# Will Helm v3 continue to work by manually adding the deprecated stable repo?

Tags: git, kubernetes-helm, deprecated

I am using the latest available version of the charts in the [stable helm repo](https://github.com/helm/charts) for some deployments and I do not want to use any upgrades from the new migrated repositories

Will I still be able to use them after final [deprecation](https://github.com/helm/charts#deprecation-timeline) of stable repo?

This would include manually adding the repo to Helm 3 with `helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com`

Or will this also stop being available and I have to switch to the new repos no matter what?

At the repo documentation it is mentioned:

> November 13th 2020. At that time these chart repos will likely be garbage collected and no longer available

However I cannot understand if they refer to the actual repo in google storage, or the repo in helm hub.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After also posting to Github *(https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/23742)*, it seems that the actual Google Storage Buckets will be deleted as well....

So, migrating is necessary.

**UPDATE:** Last state mirror of stable charts and incubator charts will be moved to **https://charts.helm.sh/stable** and **https://charts.helm.sh/incubator** accordingly.

[Reference](https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/)